# How to aggregate sum, and convert unique row values to column names, in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have issue with pandas `pd.groupby()` function. I have DataFrame

```
data = [{'Shop': 'Venga', 'Item Name': 'Oranges', 'Measure':'Supply Cost', 'Value': '10'},
        {'Shop': 'Venga', 'Item Name': 'Oranges', 'Measure':'Product Cost', 'Value': '20'},
        {'Shop': 'Venga', 'Item Name': 'Apples', 'Measure':'Supply Cost', 'Value': '5'},
        {'Shop': 'Venga', 'Item Name': 'Apples', 'Measure':'Product Cost', 'Value': '60'},
        {'Shop': 'Mesto', 'Item Name': 'Oranges', 'Measure':'Supply Cost', 'Value': '15'},
        {'Shop': 'Mesto', 'Item Name': 'Oranges', 'Measure':'Product Cost', 'Value': '10'},
        {'Shop': 'Mesto', 'Item Name': 'Apples', 'Measure':'Supply Cost', 'Value': '80'},
        {'Shop': 'Mesto', 'Item Name': 'Apples', 'Measure':'Product Cost', 'Value': '5'},
       ]
```

[image: Look like this)]

I want to move my categories of `Measure` to columns and make it look like this:

[image: Want to be like this]

I have tried to run `data.groupby(['Measure'], axis = 1).sum()` but it doesn't work at all for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use [`.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and then [`.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html#pandas.DataFrame.unstack) the correct level.

  - In this case, `level=2` is the `'Measure'` column, from the `.groupby` object.
- [`.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to remove the multi-level index.

```py
import pandas as pd

dfg = df.groupby(['Shop', 'Item Name', 'Measure'])['Value'].sum().unstack(level=2).reset_index()
dfg.columns.name = None

# display(dfg)
    Shop Item Name Product Cost Supply Cost
0  Mesto    Apples            5          80
1  Mesto   Oranges           10          15
2  Venga    Apples           60           5
3  Venga   Oranges           20          10
```